# Flow error with deep subtypes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

According to the [Subtypes of objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/subtypes/#toc-subtypes-of-objects) documentation of flow, this works

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: string };
type ObjectB = { foo: string, bar: number };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: 'test', bar: 42 };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB; // Works!
```

But a deeper implementation of this doesn't

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB; // Error! Why?
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, you can either reuse the `objectB` instance with slight modification to the ObjectA type or you can create a new object. Let's dig into your options:

## Marking an object property as covariant

What you're trying to do is to cast an `ObjectB` to an `ObjectA`. The reason Flow is complaining is that the type of `foo` in `ObjectA` is [invariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-invariance) by default. The `foo` property of `ObjectB` is a subtype of the `foo` property of `ObjectA`. To get Flow to understand this, we just need to mark the `foo` property as [covariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-covariance):

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAb1AGpJZYAuW0PAQwCc2BnZNwCWAOwDmoAL5SA3CgzZ8RUgCEq7Jq3ZdeoAcPEAaDpwBe-QaInTJcxNEzJQsQiWQq2St2up1NbOh02AHIARgAmAGZg4y5zUGCAFgBWADZgqVl7R2dXUjJPPPJ1F2V3GVAQUAB1ZgALZmMRWFBMbm5YbiA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { +foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB; // Woohoo, no error
```

Marking the property as "covariant" basically says that you promise to only read that property, you won't write to it. See, if you deleted the `baz` property of objectA it would remove `baz` from objectB. By marking it as covariant, Flow will throw an error if you write to it:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAb1AGpJZYAuW0PAQwCc2BnZNwCWAOwDmoAL5SA3CgzZ8RUgCEq7Jq3ZdeoAcPEAaDpwBe-QaInTJcxNEzJQsQiWQq2St2up1NbOh02AHIARgAmAGZg4y5zUGCAFgBWADZgqVl7R2dXUjJPPPJ1F2V3O1K3MgA6TXUaIITYAAsAWhbjABNMB2RMTpNTUFFcspVg21AQAFFublhuIA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { +foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB;

objectA.foo = {bar: 'oh-oh, deleted baz in objectB'}; //Error
```

This pattern also works for deeper-nested objects:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAb1AGpJZYAuWhvAQwCc26uAXmwDOybgEsAdgHNQAX3nyA3CgzZ8RUgCEq7Jq3ZdehzgA8RYqdIA0oQRYkzFCuSsTRMyULEIlkWtg0-HWo6fT47Hgiuc1AAcgBGACYAZjjbe3iAFgBWADY452V3T29fUjJA8vJdH01-JVAQUAB1ZgALZltJWFBMbm5YbiA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { +foo: { +bar: { baz: string } } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: { bax: string, baz: string } } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: { bax: '123', baz: '456' } } };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB; // Woohoo, no error
```

See the Flow docs on [depth subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/depth-subtyping/) for more details about this typing.

## Using `$ReadOnly<T>`

Flow has a utlity type, [`$ReadOnly<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) to mark all properties of an object as covariant, so you might want to use that instead:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAEgCVMBDAExwDtpUAeAb1EliwAXKD55GAJxEBnZBICWbAOagAvmoB8AbhQZs+IqQBCVUf0EixkmXMVKANKHEAvGwuVq1OxNEzJQsIQkyEYiBsEm1HwCwmbiUqAA5ACMAEwAzImOLiKJACwArABsiZ6qOr7+gYbkYUGkFNTVEVqgIKAA6oIAFoKObLCgmBISsBJAA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = $ReadOnly<{ foo: { bar: string } }>;
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = objectB; // Woohoo, no error
```

Or you can create a ReadOnly instance of ObjectA and leave the ObjectA definition alone:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAb1EllgC5bQ8BDAJxYGdlOAlgDsA5qAC+EgNwoM2fEVIAhKqwbNWHbqD6DRAGjbsAXr37Cxk8TMTRMyULEIlkSlgpcrqddSzpaWAHIARgAmAGZAww5TUECAFgBWADZAiWlbe0dnUjIWABIAJUx2ABMcIWhUAB4PXIA+VSdFVylQEFAAdUYAC0ZDIVhQTE5OWE5EIA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: $ReadOnly<ObjectA> = objectB; // Woohoo, no error
```

## Creating a new object

Alternatively, you can create a new copy of the object with a spread and avoid all this typing:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPICMArTAY2QEFQBeUAb1EllgC5bQ8BDAJxYGdlOAlgDsA5qAC+EgNwoM2fEVIAhKqwbNWHbqD6DRAGjbsAXr37Cxk8TMTRMyULEIlkSlgpcrqddSzpaWAHIARgAmAGZAww5TUECAFgBWADZAiWlbe0dnUjJ3HPJVGgA6UqdFV3EgA))

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = {...objectB} // Create a new object
```

But that will only work one level deep and it creates an additional object. Typically I skip this option and end up using `$ReadOnly<T>` when I need to use an object in a read-only manner.

Comment: If my response (or another) answers your question, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer (and get your question out of the "unanswered" bucket of questions)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one possible approach is to spread out the object. Without this flow is not able to read the property.

```
// @flow
type ObjectA = { foo: { bar: string } };
type ObjectB = { foo: { bar: string, baz: string } };

let objectB: ObjectB = { foo: { bar: '123', baz: '456' } };
let objectA: ObjectA = {...objectB}; // spread operator applied
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure this only works one level deep (from when I played around with this question)